# Why can' Lightning link to any message in my Thunderbird mailbox?

Tags: email-integration

Is anybody aware of a feature use email messages in Thunderbird as attachments to tasks or calendar entries in Lightning or is something along these lines planned for the next version?

I'm aware of the "convert to ..." feature but that is not what I need because this only creates a copy of the message body part without the message's attachments and recipients which doesn't help me to easily get back the complete message to create a reply or work on whatever other aspect I need the full message for.

Thunderbrowse uses a link format to go back to the original message, e.g.
"mailbox:///M|/PortableApps/ThunderbirdPortable/Data/profile/Mail/Local%20Folders/Inbox?number=54412981"
but pasting such a link in the attachment field unfortunately doesn't work in Lightning. I've also tried alternative URL formats but so far nothing worked.

Ideally, when creating a task or calendar entry from an email message such an attachment link to the original mail(s) should be added automatically because it's based on Thunderbird internal information, e.g. message number, and ideally it should be independent of the actual folder location of the message, i.e. I should be able to file it in some other folder after creating the task from the message in the Inbox and the link should still work.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/332492/how-to-link-to-emails-in-thunderbird

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on for Thunderbird called [Thunderlink](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/thunderlink/) which may help:

> ThunderLink
>
> ThunderLink lets you link to email messages in Thunderbird.
>
> Need links from your personal wiki (such as "TiddlyWiki") to certain
>   messages in your inbox?
>
> Or maybe you have a Wiki running at your company and you want to link
>   to emails sent to a mailing list so that your colleagues can quickly
>   access them without having to search their inboxes first?
>
> Use a ThunderLink!

Comment: Unfortunately ThunderLink isn't supported on my platoform (Thunderbird 31.1.0 on MacOSX 10.9.4).