# How to link to emails in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I often take personal notes in text files. Sometimes I'd like to refer to an email in one of my IMAP email boxes. Now I manually write something like `"email in <imap_account>, <date>"`, but then looking up those emails takes too much time.

Is it possible to make a link to an email, so that Thunderbird would display that specific email?

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/257234/why-can-lightning-link-to-any-message-in-my-thunderbird-mailbox

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible directly in ThunderBird.

But there is extension [ThunderLink](https://github.com/mikehardy/thunderlink) which do exactly what you want. Unfortunately it is not working in latest TB version (after switch to web extensions I suppose). Good news is the new developer looks [ready to get it working](https://github.com/mikehardy/thunderlink/issues/7).

Comment: Update: currently working implementation seems to be https://camiel.bouchier.be/en/cb_thunderlink
Caveat: see https://camiel.bouchier.be/en/cb_thunderlink/installation?with_menu=1 for installation notes - the thunderbird extension store does not feature a complete install

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using something like [xnote++](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/xnotepp/) or one of the other note taking addons for Thunderbird. The mail is stored in an mbox format and I don't see a built in method for pulling the message index. There are some external tools you could use for that, but that would be an additional process you'd have to maintain. Another option is to save the mail you want to link to with the text note, you can then just drop the message path into your note.

Comment: Saving the mail is not sufficient for me, I often want to make a note about replying to an email. I hoped someone implemented some URI scheme for IMAP (all my mailboxes are IMAP), maybe something like RFC5092...